# Pandas , Groupby function on Dattime object Vs String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, iot

I'm working on time series data analysis. I want to perform a plot of daily mean Temperature per place. Place can be 'IN' or 'OUT.

The result i get is not as expected. So i tested with adding pd.to_datetime as recommended and this gets me what i want but still it is not clear what happens inittially without converting 'daily' column to date time object.

```
` # added pd.to_datetime
tsdf['daily'] = tsdf['date'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

tsdf['daily']=tsdf['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))  

tsdf['date'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

daily_temp_mean_in=tsdf[tsdf['Place']=='In'].groupby('daily').agg({'temp': ['mean']})

daily_temp_mean_in.columns=[f"{i[0]}_{i[1]}" for i in daily_temp_mean_in.columns]

daily_temp_mean_out= tsdf[tsdf['Place']=='Out'].groupby('daily').agg({'temp' : ['mean']})

daily_temp_mean_out.columns=[f"{i[0]}_{i[1]}" for i in daily_temp_mean_out.columns]


hv.Curve(daily_temp_mean_in, label='In')* hv.Curve(daily_temp_mean_out, label='Out').opts(title="Monthly Temperature Mean", ylabel="Temperature", xlabel='Month', width=700, height=300,tools=['hover'],show_grid=True)`
```

my DataFrame:

```
room_id/id  Date    temp    Place   Month   Year    day Weekday WeekOfYear  Hour    Minute  Season  timing  Month-Year  daily
0   Room Admin  2018-07-28 07:06:00 31.0    In  7   2018    28  Saturday    30  7   6   Monsoon morning 2018-07 2018-07-28
1   Room Admin  2018-07-28 07:07:00 31.0    Out 7   2018    28  Saturday    30  7   7   Monsoon morning 2018-07 2018-07-28
2   Room Admin  2018-07-28 07:07:00 32.0    In  7   2018    28  Saturday    30  7   7   Monsoon morning 2018-07 2018-07-28
3   Room Admin  2018-07-28 07:08:00 31.0    Out 7   2018    28  Saturday    30  7   8   Monsoon morning 2018-07 2018-07-28
4   Room Admin  2018-07-28 07:08:00 31.0    In  7   2018    28  Saturday    30  7   8   Monsoon morning 2018-07 2018-07-28
```

Output 1: (not as expected)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA9ea.png)

Output 2: exactly what i want
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeO8V.png)

```
 # added pd.to_datetime

tsdf['daily'] = tsdf['date'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

tsdf['daily']=tsdf['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))  

tsdf['date'].apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

daily_temp_mean_in=tsdf[tsdf['Place']=='In'].groupby('daily').agg({'temp': ['mean']})

daily_temp_mean_in.columns=[f"{i[0]}_{i[1]}" for i in daily_temp_mean_in.columns]

daily_temp_mean_out= tsdf[tsdf['Place']=='Out'].groupby('daily').agg({'temp' : ['mean']})

daily_temp_mean_out.columns=[f"{i[0]}_{i[1]}" for i in daily_temp_mean_out.columns]


hv.Curve(daily_temp_mean_in, label='In')* hv.Curve(daily_temp_mean_out, label='Out').opts(title="Monthly Temperature Mean", ylabel="Temperature", xlabel='Month', width=700, height=300,tools=['hover'],show_grid=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking why does a plot look better after you have specified that these string labels for the x-axis actually are dates? But then both code snippets looks absolutely the same to me, so I don't know what you are testing in fact.

Comment: also please remove tag iot

Comment: There are 2 cases; 1/ i used daily column as string type. 2/ i convert daily column to datettime using pd.to_datetime. Then the result of these 2 cases is in the 2 screenshots  i attached. The problem that it is not clear why i need to convert Daily column to datetime object to get the plot i want ? so this my question.